# Handlebars.SafeString() issue in Meteor?

Tags: templates, meteor, handlebars.js

I have did a sample example of dynamic loading templates using the `Handlebars.SafeString()`. Everything works fine expect  **Refresh the browser URL**. When ever refresh the browser url i get an error i.e **"Uncaught TypeError: Property 'undefined' of object # is not a function"**.And this error get only this line i.e `return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')]({dataKey: 'somevalue'}));`. With out this line **Works fine everything even Refresh also**.I am using this `Handlebars.SafeString()` is to load templates dynamically. I didn't have any idea about this So please help me how to?.

And What is the use of `dataKey` in above Handlebars.SafeString()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `Session` dict is not populated when the call is made, and therefore `Session.get('currentTemplate')` is undefined. A simple safeguard should fix the problem, assuming you're in a reactive context:

```
if(! Session.get('currentTemplate')) return '';
return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')]({dataKey: 'somevalue'}));
```

Comment: I would recommend using `Session.setDefault('currentTemplate', 'myHomeTemplate')` instead. http://docs.meteor.com/#session_set_default

Comment: In this particular case, using `setDefault` would cause a different template to draw for a fraction of second, and therefore a worse flicker. It's better to use [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) for the purpose of setting the main template.